# Security decorator for Hibernate collection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, security, aop

I'm facing a conceptual problem : how to filter access on some attributes of an entity loaded by Hibernate ?

For instance : I have a Car with a collection (set or bag) of 4 Wheels (2 are red, 2 are blue ; bidirectionnal link) ; User A has right to see red and blue wheels, User B can only see blue ones.  When I retrieve Cars, wheels are fetched too (sometimes through Hibernate.initialize, sometimes through a fetch directly in query).

When I request for Cars, I would like to find a way to filter wheels to only the ones that user has rights to see. (Filtering results after DB loading is OK for the moment)

I would like to keep filtering mechanism as less as intrusive.

**What doesn't work :**

- @Filter (or @Where) : credential check is a bit tricky, and I have some other joins to do to know if user is allowed or not to see wheels ;
- Spring ACL : my credential management is too tricky to use this (moreover, not sure if it is able to filter inner attributes) ;

**Implemented solution :**

- Define a custom UserCollectionType, and provide a Collection Decorator retrieving only authorised data (overload iterator(), get(int index),...) ; **drawback :** my collection is not coherent : when a data is added, it is accessible only if current user is allowed. Not sure it's a reliable solution.

**Other solutions :**

- **AOP on domain object** : this is, I think, the best ; add AOP on my domain object, which defines accessor to it's collection of authorizable entities, and filter them at access time. Inconvenient : add AOP on domain object loaded by hibernate may be tricky ? ( cf. [Spring AOP Advice for Hibernate managed POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669003/spring-aop-advice-for-hibernate-managed-pojo) )
- **Hibernate Interceptor/Event** : I tried to use this, but did not found the good place to do what I want, without being intrusive. And I don't want to "really" modify loaded collections : it must be transparent for hibernate (I don't want Hibernate to remove red wheels from car every time User B access to them in a non readonly transaction).
- **AOP + Introspection on exposed services** : outside transactional context, filter every collection attribute of every entity recursively to remove unauthorized elements ; maybe the easier and less intrusive solution ; **drawback** : collections attributes cannot stay unmodifiable ;

**What do you think about implemented solution ? Any other idea on how to do this ?**

(Context is :  Hibernate 4.1.3, Spring 3.1.1, java 7)

Thanks !

Comment: what do you think about mix approch @Filter and use AOP around DAO to enable or disable filter based on access rights.

Comment: I can't use Filter because security because credential model is a bit complex ; I'm not able to generate a simple and appropriate Filter clause for every case.

Comment: Good question. I liked this interceptor approach: http://mattfleming.com/node/243